# Can 'rake db:seed' tell you which record it is choking on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When seeding data, I sometimes get an error like this:

```
Owner(#70279918514200) expected, got String(#70279913263500)
```

Would it be possible for Rake to tell me what record it is choking on?

EDIT:

This has a little more info on what I'm looking for:

I have a flat file which indicates the data I need. This file was created from an unvalidated database that had many different spelling for things like Proctor (and|y|avec|gen) Gamble. I have been able to translate almost all of them, but there have been some that slip through the cracks and still give me trouble. Would it be possible to see from rake which line of the flat file when I run

```
flat_file.each_line
```

is causing trouble?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running `rake db:seed --trace` to see what line of your `seed.rb` file is failing.

**Edit #1:**  Now that I know you're using `each_line`, you may just need to keep a manual count to determine line number.

```
line_count = 0
flat_file.each_line do |line|
  begin
    line_count += 1
    # code for handling `line` goes here
  rescue => e
    puts "Error happened on line #{line_count}: #{e}"
  end
end
```

**Edit #2:** If you're loading your full file and not streaming it in from its source, you can also get rid of the manual `line_count` variable that you otherwise have to track with a little help from the [String#lines](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-lines) method.

```
file_contents.lines.each_with_index do |line, line_count|
  begin
    # code for handling `line` goes here
  rescue => e
    puts "Error happened on line #{line_count}: #{e}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Rake typically tells you to re-run with --trace when it crashes, you'll get used to it!

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for, though still good advice. I would want to know when I run owners_file.each_line, which line is it that is causing trouble. After making this structured file from an unorganized database, I still miss translating some of the alternate, like Proctor (and|y|avec|gen) Gamble, into the integer I'm supposed to. If rake coud help me out with that, it'd be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the error in your load script and throw a new one with the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could call .valid? on your object prior to creating it and if that fails print out the error messages and any other attributes of the record in question somewhere for later review.